# Laravel - can't find() attached object in many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

in my POST form users are able to add other users to a room.
I put a unique constraint on the link (no duplicate entry in the link between users and rooms).
However when I refresh my page (f5) after submitting the form, Laravel complains about duplicate entries, although I do check if the objects are attached before.

Here's the code:

```
$roomUsers = Room::find($request->room_id)->users();

if ($request->add != null) {
    foreach ($request->add as $uId)
        // if null, user hasnt been attach yet
        if (!$roomUsers->find($uId)) {
            Log::debug($roomUsers->find($uId) == null ? 'null' : 'not null');
            // then we can attach him
            $roomUsers->attach($uId);
        }
}
```

The line `!$roomUsers->find($uId)` **returns true** yet the object has been attached in the previous iteration. How is that possible ? Thanks

Comment: Could you post the controller function for this action?

Comment: Post your Models too, where you have defined the relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're above code isn't working is because you're not creating a new instance of `BelongsToMany` for each check. This means that every time you call `find` you're not actually creating a new query you're just adding to the existing one e.g.

say you the ids to add are `[1, 2, 3]` by the last check your query would effectively be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND id = 2 AND id = 3
```

To keep with the above logic you could do:

```
$room = Room::find($request->room_id);

if ($request->add != null) {
    foreach ($request->add as $uId)
        // if null, user hasnt been attach yet
        if (!$room->users()->find($uId)) {
            // then we can attach him
            $room->users()->attach($uId);
        }
}
```

Or a much simpler way to go about this would be to `syncWithoutDetaching`.

Your code could then look something like:

```
$roomUsers = Room::find($request->room_id);

if ($request->has('add')) {
    $roomUsers->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($request->add);
}
```

Hope this helps!